# c# convert string that has ctrl+z to regular string

Tags: c#

i have a string like this:

some_string="A simple demo of SMS text messaging." + Convert.ToChar(26));

what is the SIMPLEST way of me getting rid of the char 26?

please keep in mind that sometimes some_string has char 26 and sometimes it does not, and it can be in different positions too, so i need to know what is the most versatile and easiest way to get rid of char 26?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it can be in different positions (not just the end):

```
someString = someString.Replace("\u001A", "");
```

Note that you have to use the return value of `Replace` - strings are immutable, so any methods which *look* like they're changing the contents actually return a new string with the appropriate changes.

Answer (score 4):

If it's only at the end:

```
some_string.TrimEnd((char)26)
```

If it can be anywhere then forget this and use Jon Skeet's answer.